# How to get user's response of Share location prompt in browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, geoip, maxmind

I am using MaxMind GeoIP2 JavaScript API to determine a user's location when they enter my website. This prompts the user for their permission to provide the location via the browser. I want user's response of this prompt. So how can I get this response? I select 'Not Now' or 'Never for this site' then also it shares location. Please help me.

Comment: Their documentation seems pretty good, have you checked it out? http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/javascript/

Comment: I read but nothing wriiten about browser prompt response